# How do I use GAMs in instrumental variable analysis?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, instrumental-variables

I have an outcome $Y$, a risk factor $X$, and an instrument $Z$.

In a two-stage least squares (2SLS) setting, the first stage is

$$
X=Z + \varepsilon
$$
and the second stage uses predictions from the first stage
$$
Y = \hat X + \eta.
$$

Now my setting is a bit more complicated. Say $Y$=quality of life, a continuous variable, $X$= BMI, and $Z$=BMI of a biological relative.

The literature suggests that the relationship between quality of life and BMI is U-shaped, low BMI is bad, high BMI is bad, but "normal" BMI is good for your QoL.

Can I fit this model using a GAM in the second stage, like this:

$$
X=Z + age + sex 
$$

$$
Y = f(\hat X) + age + sex
$$

where $f$ is the spline function of a GAM. I omitted error terms and added covariates that I adjust for.

Do you have an example code in R?